# I don't get why my API Request is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, openweathermap

I'm working on a weather app, on top of having the option to get his geolocation the user can also input a city to get the weather info.
I've been stuck for a while, I'm trying to get the info of the weather using the input of the user, using my api request(which is working on codepen // I'm working on VSCode). Im using the same url of my geoLocation but changing it to taking the city instead of the lon and lat as input, but I always get a ERROr 400, but I can't seem to locate the source of my error.

```
// Get weather from input

function getVal() {
  var val = document.querySelector('#search-city').value;

  const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + val + '&appid={API key}&units=metric';

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (data) => {
      $('#city').text(data.name)
      $('#condition').text(data.weather[0].main);
      $('h1').text(Math.round(data.main.temp));

      backgroundChange(data.weather[0].main);
    },
    error: () => {
      return false
    }
  });
};

// Get weather using location

function geoLocation() {
  if ('geolocation' in navigator) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      let lat = position.coords.latitude;
      let long = position.coords.longitude;

      let url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long + '&appid={API Key}&units=metric';

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
          $('#city').text(data.name)
          $('#condition').text(data.weather[0].main);
          $('h1').text(Math.round(data.main.temp));

          backgroundChange(data.weather[0].main);
        },
        error: () => {
          return false
        }
      });
    })
  };
});
```

I would really appreciate your help !
Thank you very much!!

// RESOLVED

At first I created the function outside of my onlick event and the API Call was made even before the event was called, so I think the input couldn't make it's way to the URL.
Here is the modify version which is now working :

$('.search-icon').click(
function getVal() {

```
    var city = document.querySelector('#search-city').value;

    const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+'&appid=dc8c9152e8adaad0ec8bf635818c0d42&units=metric';
      
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
            $('#city').text(data.name)
            $('#condition').text(data.weather[0].main);
            $('h1').text(Math.round(data.main.temp));

            backgroundChange(data.weather[0].main);
        },
        error: () => {
            return false
        }
    });
    

    
});
```

Comment: In your real code you replace `{API key}` with your actual key, right?

Comment: I suggest you put the parameters in the `data:` option of `$.ajax`. It will automatically add them to the URL, ensuring that they're encoded properly.

Comment: Are they both failing, or just the one that gets the input from the user?

Comment: Does the 400 error include a detailed error message?

Comment: To mark your question resolved please accept an answer, or write an answer yourself and accept that. Don’t forget to upvote answers which helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this part of API's url "ppid={API Key}" you are passing as a string. You should inform your API key in order to fetch the data.

Comment: That may just be a placeholder here so he doesn't show his actual API key.

Comment: yes, but that should be in a variable, but that way is just a string. Its a typo maybe

Comment: That would probably be best, but it should also work by putting it directly into the string. I asked in a comment whether that's the real code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses but I found the solution ! Instead of creating an event using the function, I put the function in the event.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).